# Difference between .irb_history and .irb-history

Tags: ruby, irb

What the difference is between the `.irb-history` and `.irb_history` files in Ruby?

Comment: What version(s) of Ruby do you have installed? Do you actually have both files present on the same machine?

Comment: I have version 1.9.3-p125 and 1.8.7 installed. Both files exist under my home dir. I am wondering if both one is related to one version and the other the other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your version `"#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history"` or  `"#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb_history"` files contain the list of all the lines that one has typed into to the irb, you can do a `cat ~/.irb-history` to see the contents and also `irbrc.rb` file will give your move details into this.

Answer (score 0):

Which line editing library are you linking with Ruby?

I believe if you build ruby with GNU readline, it's using .irb-history, and
if you link with libedit (if Ruby configure can't find readline), it's using .irb_history.

Comment: I have the version OSX comes with but I also installed this version:
https://gist.github.com/1688857

using cat on both files it seems one corresponds to the default OSX installation and the other is from the git version I installed.

Comment: Ok. You're using the falcon patch. (I guess that does not matter..)

Realized that I might used the system installed ruby (I'm using OSX too) so I tried both /usr/bin/irb which linked with libedit, RVM built with GNU readline. Both writes to .irb-history, so my guess was wrong.

Comment: I compiled my Ruby with GNU readline from Homebrew, but it still only sees `~/.irb_history`.

Comment: @FranklinYu I guess this post is two years ago, thus things might be changed.